# Azure Event Processor Host java library - ReceiverRuntimeInformation doesn't have actual stats on a partition

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

I am trying to get the last enqueued sequence number to track the lag between consumer and producer at the consumer end by leveraging ReceiverRuntimeInformation object provided by PartitionContext when a event is received. However, ReceiverRuntimeInformation object doesn't have the updated values related to that particular partition of an Event Hub, it returns 0. Sample code and log output below:

```
public class EventProcessor extends IEventProcessorImpl{

    @Override
    public void onEvents(PartitionContext context, Iterable<EventData> messages) throws Exception {
            ReceiverRuntimeInformation rte = context.getRuntimeInformation();
            logger.info(rte.getLastEnqueuedOffset() + " * " + rte.getLastEnqueuedSequenceNumber() + " * " + rte.getPartitionId() + " * " +  rte.getRetrievalTime());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
null * 0 * 3 * null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an opt-in feature. While creating the `EventProcessorHost` instance, pass in `EventProcessorOptions` with:

`eventProcessorOptions.setReceiverRuntimeMetricEnabled(true);`

We designed this as an `Opt-in` feature - as it adds additional bytes to all EventHub messages received (sdk uses all `EventData` received on the wire by the client - to transmit this extra information).

**Note**: Data present in `RecieverRuntimeInformation` is `dynamic` and hence can be `stale`! For instance - `ReceiverRuntimeInformation.LastEnqueuedSequenceNumber` could change by the time service actually responded back! as there could be new Events on that Partition. To make the data relevant - we added a property named - `RetrievalTime` - which is actually when the `ReceiverRuntimeInformation` was retrieved from the service. This can help understand - how stale the value of `ReceiverRuntimeInformation` is.

Comment: Thanks Sreeram, I am able to see sequence numbers after enabling runtime metrics. However, there are times when the last enqueued sequence number is lower than the sequence number of the current message that is being processed. Do you have any idea on why this would happen?

Comment: @tj23 - updated the answer - (n)ack - if that addresses what you saw.